# Making Raspberry Pi a wifi hotspot

Tags: wifi, hotspot

I followed the following tutorial https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/ and I am successful in making my Pi3 an access point. The internet connection from eth0 is getting shared to users connecting through wlan0. How do I stop it?

I am new to networking and Linux. How do I debug the problem?

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I am not able to connect to internet through the access point

Comment: What operating system are you using to connect to the access point? Does it connect to the AP? Does it get an IP address? Does it get other network configuration such as default route, DNS etc?

Comment: I am trying to connect from my laptop which runs windows. My phone runs android

Comment: Let me check if it gets an IP

Comment: Strangely, I receive whatsapp messages only. I don't receive any data on other apps such as instagram or reddit for fun.

Comment: When you open a Web browser and enter an address, what happens? If it shows an error message, what does it say? If you open a command prompt and type `ping www.bbc.co.uk`, what happens? (All on the Windows pc.)

Comment: It started working fine without me having to do anything. I used to get an exclamation with the wifi network saying its not connected, but not anymore.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSmith for your responses. What could have been the reason it started working now?

Comment: I don't know - you didn't answer any of the questions I asked to help diagnose it. Glad it's working now anyway.

Comment: I started to  find what you asked for and it started working seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem, I didn´t receive any response from my phone (except WhatsApp). 
After red this report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/876458), I remove ´bind-interfaces´ from dnsmasq.conf. And it solve this problem.

Comment: This problem still persists for me. The bug connects to Ubuntu `dnsmasq` package and not from the Rasbian repo. Does anyone have any other working solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a git repository to do one click setup. the main jobs are install tools for hotpots service, and script code to run in station mode and access point mode.
http://www.mlabviet.com/2016/05/setup-hotspots-for-raspberry-pi-3.html
The best way to setup is connect your RPI to internet through LAN cable, you also can connect wifi before doing setup.

1. sudo ./install.sh.
2. Reboot.
3. to active access point mode: run: sudo ap [Name] [pass(optional)]
4. to active station mode: run : sudo sta [ssid] [pass]

video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6Y5Klv_nIE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Is this project mature?

Comment: Yes, it is stable now, I'm going to record the video how it work.